# Python prevent keyboard from writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I'm trying to find a way for:

- Listen for what is pressend on the keyboard
- Prevent the keyboard from writing on the screen

During my researches i found this

1) BlockInput For block the keyboard on windows ( i tried but did not work )

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

BlockInput = ctypes.windll.user32.BlockInput
BlockInput.argtypes = [wintypes.BOOL]
BlockInput.restype = wintypes.BOOL

blocked = BlockInput(True)
if blocked:
    try:
        pass # do something
    finally:
        unblocked = BlockInput(False) # unblock in any case
else:
    raise RuntimeError('Input is already blocked by another thread!')
```

2) PyHook ( old library that is not more supported )

```
import pythoncom, pyHook 

def uMad(event):
    return False

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = uMad
hm.KeyAll = uMad
hm.HookMouse()
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Any other solutions ( Win 10 ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Install PyHook for Python 3.7 64 bit or 32 bit from the below link

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

after that do a CTRL + F and search for the below

pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
pyHook‑1.5.1‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl

Go to cmd and type pip install followed by the path of your pyhook file. For example:

C:\user\download\pyHook-1.5.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

Answer (score 0):

[Try the keyboard module](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). It has methods that allow you to block the keyboard until a specific key is pressed, block it forever and listen for what key is pressed.

Some examples from the the keyboard page linked above.

```
# Blocks until you press esc.
keyboard.wait('esc')

# Record events until 'esc' is pressed.
recorded = keyboard.record(until='esc')

# Block forever, like `while True`.
keyboard.wait()
```